# LinkageError after adding javax.ws.rs-api to Gradle build in Spring Boot 3.2 Kotlin project

Tags: spring-boot, jax-rs, docker-java

## Initial Error:

Encountered a NoClassDefFoundError when building with Docker Java API on a spring boot "3.2.1" Kotlin 1.9.21 project

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/Configuration
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.JerseyDockerHttpClient$Builder.build(JerseyDockerHttpClient.java:124)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientBuilder.build(DockerClientBuilder.java:106)
    ...
```

## Attempted Solution:

Added the javax.ws.rs-api dependency to my .kts file:

```
implementation("javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.1.1")
```

## New Error After Adding Dependency:

Encountered a LinkageError related to ClientBuilder.

```
java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to cast jar:file:/home/alkaphreak/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.1.1/d3466bc9321fe84f268a1adb3b90373fc14b0eb5/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class
    at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:81)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.JerseyDockerHttpClient.<init>(JerseyDockerHttpClient.java:257)
    ...
```

Build Script (build.gradle.kts):

```
// Relevant parts of the build script
dependencies {
    // Other dependencies...
    implementation("com.github.docker-java:docker-java:3.3.4")
    implementation("com.github.docker-java:docker-java-transport-httpclient5:3.3.4")
    implementation("javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.1.1")
}
```

## Resolution Attempts :

Tried using a resolutionStrategy to force the version without success.

```
// Apply a resolution strategy to force a single version of the dependency
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        // Force usage of a specific version of 'javax.ws.rs-api'
        force("javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.1.1")
    }
}
```

## Request for Help:

I'm unable to resolve the LinkageError after adding the javax.ws.rs-api dependency.
If anyone has insights or suggestions on how to fix this issue, please advise.

PS : Opened an issue here too : https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/issues/2284#issuecomment-1871987626

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work, we can replace the code :

```
private fun dockerClient(): DockerClient = DockerClientBuilder
        .getInstance()
        .build()
```

By :

```
private fun dockerClient(): DockerClient = DockerClientBuilder
        .getInstance()
        .withDockerCmdExecFactory(NettyDockerCmdExecFactory())
        .build()
```

Note that `withDockerCmdExecFactory` is deprecated. I will try to improve that.

Source : https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/issues/2284#issuecomment-1873776989